# parseJSON data into uitableviewcell

Tags: php, ios, mysql, swift, uitableview

I want to populate array of data from mysql table into uitableviewcelll.
When I tried I got only first row of values, I am not getting other rows of data who will match the condition.

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary
print(json as Any)
```

here json is printing only one row values.

```
Optional({
Saturday = 1;
friday = 1;
message = "following Students are assigned to Teacher";
monday = 1;
perday = 1;
pid = 101;
status = 1;
sunday = 1;
thursday = 1;
tuesday = 1;
wednesday = 1;
```

})

I have next pid 104 , 106 Students in table.

Comment: can you show us the actual json string? Probably json contains multiple fragments so you can do: `.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments)`

Comment: This also doesn't work :-(